# ReferenceError: navigator is not defined on "npm run build" Nextjs @andyet/simplewebrtc

Tags: next.js

I am creating video chat app with @andyet/simplewebrtc. And I am using nextjs dynamic import. Everything is working fine on localhost but when I try to create a build with "npm run build", I am getting navigator is not defined.

> Build error occurred
> ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
> at Object. (/Users/apple/Documents/React Mac/next-webrtc/next-webrtc/node_modules/@andyet/simplewebrtc/lib/Hark.js:4:56)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object. (/Users/apple/Documents/React Mac/next-webrtc/next-webrtc/node_modules/@andyet/simplewebrtc/actions/Media.js:5:40)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) {
> type: 'ReferenceError'
> }

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @juliomalves, here is the code https://github.com/gorayaa66/simple-webrtc-test. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade to @andyet/simplewebrtc version 1.30.2 and it will resolve the issue. They made the upgrade to this version before that it was not compatible with nextjs